# Open Auth class to allow logins via facebook, google, twitter etc -> just like SO

Tags: php, authentication, openid

Is there a php library that has all the stuff I need to do logins via fb, google, twitter, yahoo etc?

Something like how the SO one works.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth is different from the open-id facebook uses oauth by that you can actually pull some facebook data while with open-id u can maintain the session just authentication is done by the open-id provider (google)

you can use the Janrain-engage for this purpose and there is also a open-source lib available named "open-id enabled" thats too now under janrain.. google it